# Intermediate Value Theorem: Show that there is a value of $x$ between $4$ and $5$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = x^2 − 5x + 2$ and $g(x) = x-5$. Using the IVT, show that there is an $x$ value between $4$ and $5$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$.

I just don't understand how the IVT can do something like this and I haven't found any similar problems online.

Comment: Hint: Set $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. What is $h(4)$ and $h(5)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$

$$h(x) = x^2-6x+7 $$

Now,

$$h(4) = -1 <0$$

$$h(5) = 2 > 0$$

Can you use IVT to put the pieces together now?